# Trying to swap 1 outlet with a switch that doesn’t control outlets

Tags: electrical

I have 3 outlets. Trying to remove 1 to put a switch to a recessed light in. But I don't want to control the outlets with the switch. What do I do?

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure you want to put a switch here? It looks like it'd be way up near the ceiling or down by the floor....

Comment: ThreePhase-it’s actually a little cubby hole/shelf/nightstand however you want to call it for like my Sonos speaker/phone charger stand/books/glasses/tv remotes. Basically a box pushed into the wall to place things. And there are these outlets in there but no form of light. So I cut a hole for recessed light and ran about 2.5-3ft of wire around the box in the other room behind the wall up to the light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the bottom one.   Black to a switch screw, the hot on the lamp's cable goes to the other switch screw.  The white does not go to the switch but goes to the lamp cable's  white wire.

Comment: Unless of course it is a smart switch that needs neutral.

Comment: Nah. Just a basic switch. But I got it by removing the bottom before reading the comments and figured trial and error. I built a mini model before putting the light in the ceiling.

Comment: Don't use trial and error on mains electrical.  There are *many* combinations which work perfectly but create an unsafe condition.

Comment: Well if it was error wouldn’t it trip the breaker back off as soon as I flipped it?

Comment: That's the problem, no.  There are many, many ways to do wiring that's "silent but deadly" and later kills or starts a fire in a way the breaker cannot catch.  It's useless for detecting electric shocks of humans, for instance, unless it's a GFCI breaker.

Comment: @RyanCamaroRS The "normal" errors will. But there are some errors - e.g., ground & neutral swapped (not likely here as ground is bare and therefore quite clearly different, but just as an example of things people do...) is dangerous because the ground wire is not required to be rated the same as hot & neutral and therefore might not be capable of safely conducting the normal load. Or combined neutrals which can overload even though the matching hots will be fine - which is a problem because only the hot is normally protected, not neutral. etc.

Comment: Well like I said. I did the way you suggested before reading any of these and it worked. Thank you for your concern for my safety though.

Comment: I would show another picture but idk how to add a 2nd picture to this post